# How to add to a score number of certain item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a score named "DirtCount", I want to **add** the number of dirt in my inventory to the score. 
I found this command that **sets** the score to the number of dirt :

```
/execute as @p store result score @s DirtCount run clear @p minecraft:dirt 0
```

But that is not what I want, I want to **add**, not **set**, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just overwrite a separate scoreboard and add them together. Assuming you have a `TempDirtCount` objective (create it with `/scoreboard objectives add TempDirtCount dummy` if not), you can do:

```
/execute as @p store result score @s TempDirtCount run clear @p minecraft:dirt 0
/scoreboard players operation @p DirtCount += @p TempDirtCount
```